# File will not upload, PHP

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I've written PHP scripts to upload files in the past, but for some reason this one isn't working…

The HTML looks like:

```
<form action="scripts/submit.php" method="push" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="submitGraphics" id="submitGraphics">
      <p>
        <label for="filefield"><strong class="red">*</strong> File:</label>
        <input name="filefield" type="file" id="filefield" tabindex="30" />
      </p>
</form>
```

The script looks like:

```
<?php

    $fileName = $_FILES["filefield"]["name"];
    $fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["filefield"]["tmp_name"];
    $fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["filefield"]["error"];

    echo "$fileName";
    echo "$fileTmpLoc";
    echo "$fileErrorMsg";
    print_r($_FILES);
?>
```

There is normally more afterwards, but I am now just testing to make sure the file is uploading (since it has not been working).  All I get from this is nothing for the first three echo statements, and then a line saying `Array()`.

I have modified the php.ini file in the nesesarry spots:

`file_uploads`
`upload_max_filesize`
`max_execution_time`
`post_max_size`

Comment: Make sure to add tag with this attribute: `enctype="multipart/form-data"`
Without it the files will not uploaded.

Comment: @user2511140 He already has that tag...

Comment: What is in `$_FILES`? Do a `print_r` or `var_dump` on it and put the output in your post.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen $_FILES is `Array()`, as posted above.

Comment: Then woopti-doo. Nothing was submitted, which probably means that there is something wrong with your HTML... which would be `method="push"`. The [HTTP protocol does not have a `push` method](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#page-36); you probably meant to write `post`, yeah?

Comment: Also, if the `$_FILES` array is empty then your code should show some "Undefined index" notices. You should [turn on errors and such](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php#answer-845025).

Comment: It was supposed to be `post`, you're right.  Don't know where `push` came from.  And yeah, some of you are answering without even reading the question - a little too anxious to be first up.

Comment: @Michael Or the answers for that matter :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `method="push"` to `method="post"`

Comment: Can anyone explain the low-quality flag?